# Referencing ProgramFiles folder in WixProj Bootstrapper

Tags: msbuild, wix

(I've looked at other answers to no avail).

In my WixProj file, I have a few bootstrapper calls referencing necessary files.

```
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Case Tracking" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="False" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="$(env.ProgramFiles)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\BootStrapper" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" Culture="en-US" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' " />
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Case Tracking" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="False" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="$(env.ProgramFiles)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\BootStrapper" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" Culture="en-US" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug Web|x86' " />
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Case Tracking" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="False" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="$(env.ProgramFiles)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\BootStrapper" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" Culture="en-US" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' " />
```

The problem with the above code is that when it attempts to build, I get the error

The expression """.ProgramFiles" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.ProgramFiles' not found.

So how can I reference the ProgramFiles environment within the WixProj file?

The Project builds properly locally - it just won't build properly through MSBuild.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the WixProj file, the "env." isn't required. Instead, you can just refer to it as ${ProgramFiles}\Microsoft.....

References in the wxs file may need to use the $(env.ProgramFiles) but the WixProj which is a Build file uses the built-in constants.